# Difference between id and data-dojo-id

Tags: dojo

What is the difference between an id and a data-dojo-id in a dojo tag such as this:

```
<button id="save" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:save">Save</button>
```

I try to reference this button to change it's label with:
    var myButton = dijit.byId("save");
so that I can change the button label
    myButton.set("label", "Add New");

If I use id="save" it works. If I only use data-dojo-id="save" it doesn't work.

I'm fairly new to Dojo so an explanation or tutorial you can point me to would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

`data-dojo-id` assigns widget into global namespace, i.e. into `window` object:

```
<button data-dojo-id="save" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Save</button>​
```

so you can access the button directly:

```
save.set("label", "Add New");
```

See the difference in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/7yV56/

**EDIT:** To answer your questions. I do not use `data-dojo-id` at all. It pollutes global namespace which is the direct opposite of what the AMD does. Anyway, you can still use something like `widgets.save` and `widgets.rename` to minimize the pollution:

```
<button data-dojo-id="widgets.save" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Save</button>​
<button data-dojo-id="widgets.rename" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Rename</button>​
```

IMO, `data-dojo-id` is there for [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement), not for fully-fledged applications.

`data-dojo-id` just assigns an instance to a variable, so with multiple dijits with the same `data-dojo-id` the variable will point to the last one assigned (i.e. it'll not be an array).

You can avoid extensive use of `registry.byId` writing your method to obtain widgets according to your needs. The best way to start is [`dijit/registy.findWidgets(rootNode, skipNode)`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dijit/registry#findWidgets). Please also note, that [`dojo/parser.parse(rootNode, options)`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojo/parser#parse) returns an array of instantiated objects, or more precisely:

> Returns a blended object that is an array of the instantiated objects,
>   but also can include a promise that is resolved with the instantiated
>   objects. This is done for backwards compatibility. If the parser
>   auto-requires modules, it will always behave in a promise fashion and
>   `parser.parse().then(function(instances){...})` should be used.

An example of a method I use to assign ContentPane's dijits into its `widgets` property, which is an object:

```
_attachTemplateWidgets: function(widgets) {
    widgets = widgets || this.getChildren();
    for(var each = 0; each < widgets.length; each++) {
        var widget = widgets[each];
        var attachPoint = widget.params.dojoAttachPoint;
        if(attachPoint) {
            this.widget[attachPoint] = widget;
        }

        var children = widget.getChildren();
        if(children.length > 0) {
           this._attachTemplateWidgets(children);
        }
    }
}
```

I put the entire class here: https://gist.github.com/3754324. I use this `app.ui._Pane` instead of `dijit/layout/ContentPane`.

Comment: Thanks Phusick! Using just the id attribute requires the use of using byId method to get the DOM hook. Now I wonder which is better for use in a Dojo module where you are creating multiple instances. Does data-dojo-id take care of managing that internally so one instance identity is not being confused with another?